# OnSaveInstanceState and OnRestoreInstanceState not saving on app quit

Tags: java, android

I am trying to save my programmatically created CardView and TextView using **OnSaveInstanceState** and **OnRestoreInstanceState** as in the sample code. 
While debugging, I notice that values are saved but when I quit the app and reopen it, nothing is being restored. 
What am I doing wrong?

```
**@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putString("key", userInput.getText().toString());
    savedInstanceState.putInt("LayoutId", mConstraintLayout.getId());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.getString("key");
    savedInstanceState.getInt("LayoutId");
}**
```

This are the methods I am using after 'OnCreate'

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mContext = getApplicationContext();
    mConstraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.top_left);
    addButton = findViewById(R.id.add);
    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                     @Override
                                     public void onClick(View v) {
                                         View popup = findViewById(R.id.popup);
                                         popup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                     }
                                 });

    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.create);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final CardView sticker = new CardView(mContext);
            CardView.LayoutParams params = new CardView.LayoutParams(
                    CardView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    CardView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );
            params.height=500;
            params.width=500;

            CheckBox privateCalendar = findViewById(R.id.checkPrivate);
            CheckBox workCalendar = findViewById(R.id.checkWork);
            CheckBox holidayCalendar = findViewById(R.id.checkHoliday);
            if (privateCalendar.isChecked()){
                sticker.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
            }
            else if (workCalendar.isChecked()){
                sticker.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF8080"));
            }
            else if (holidayCalendar.isChecked()){
                sticker.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#66B3FF"));
            }
            else{
                sticker.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
            }

            sticker.setId(CardView.generateViewId());
            sticker.getId();
            sticker.setTag(CARD_VIEW_TAG);
            sticker.setLayoutParams(params);

            sticker.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence) sticker.getTag());
                    String[] mimeTypes = {ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN};
                    ClipData data = new ClipData(sticker.getTag().toString(), mimeTypes, item);
                    View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(sticker);
                    sticker.startDrag(data
                            , shadowBuilder
                            , sticker
                            , 0
                    );
                    sticker.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    return true;



                }
            });

            TextView tv = new TextView(mContext);
            tv.setLayoutParams(params);
            tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            userInput = findViewById(R.id.editText);
            tv.setText(userInput.getText());
            tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            sticker.addView(tv);
            mConstraintLayout.addView(sticker);
            View popup = findViewById(R.id.popup);
            popup.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what's the error you are getting??

Comment: I don't get any errors. Simply when I reopen the app there's no trace of what I previously added

Comment: check in android monitor and share the error

Comment: yup Android device monitor.

Comment: Please use shared preference to save persistent data. onRestoreInstancestate used only when a device configuration change like the portrait to landscape or vice-versa.

Answer (score 4):

`SavedInstanceState` and `RestoreInstanceState` will work if activity is recreated due to config change like orientation change or android system killed that activity due to memory issue, Then only `savedInstanceState` and `restoreInstanceState` comes in role.

If you finish activity by yourself and start activity again then there is no use of these methods.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I didn't know that!. What would you recommend in this case then to save my cardviews?

Comment: Why are you saving cardviews ? You don't need to save cardviews. Just save data and retrieve from bundle, then draw your ui as per data.

Comment: Because in this case cardviews are created on click and contain the data (color and text). When I restart the activity, the cardview ha to be there already

Answer (score 1):

Try to save data in SharedPreference instead savedInstanceState.

```
SharedPreferences pref = 
getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
Editor editor = pref.edit();
```

For Storing data:-

```
editor.putString("key", userInput.getText().toString());
editor.putInt("LayoutId", mConstraintLayout.getId());
editor.apply();
```

For retriving data:-

```
editor.getString("key", null); // getting String
editor.getInt("LayoutId", 0); // getting Integer
```

Comment: This is bad practice, first of all if you rebuild your app to publish a new update, that layoutId can be different, and will cause you app to crash, trying to load a resource not found in your current version...

Comment: also it should be editor.getInt("LayoutId", 0) not null.

Answer (score 0):

First of all if by "close the app" you mean destroy it, this will never work for you.

Second of all in onRestoreInstanceState you don't do anything with those values, you simply read them but don't store them anywhere.

If you mean to recreate the old form after switching back and forth between apps, with your app being destroyed in the background then, you need to only set values in onSaveInstanceState like you did, and in onCreate(Bundle savedInstance), you should do something like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(savedInstance == null) {
        //read values from getIntent()
        key = getIntent().getString("key);
        LayoutId = getIntent().getInt("LayoutId");
    } else {
       //read values from savedInstanceState

       key = savedInstanceState.getString("key");
       LayoutId = savedInstanceState.getInt("LayoutId");
    }
}
```